# How to get Instagram permanent Access token?

Tags: php, instagram

I want Permanent access token for **Instagram** so that my Customers doesn't need to login again and we should be able to access the user account using Access token directly.

Is it possible to do that ?

Please suggest me the best way.

Comment: By default Instagram `access_token` never change (the string) nor expires, even if the user revoke access to that app and re-authorize it, the access_token never change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask user to login for the first time. upon his successful login, save the access token returned by the Instagram API. Use this access token to send signed requests to Instagram API.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can you please explain how we can send signed request after getting access_token ?

Comment: All you need to do is append the access token with the URL.

Please check the following link for further explanation.
http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/